# Software for Computations with Complexes

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

What software would you recommend for working with chain complexes? In particular I'd like to be able to compute cohomology of a finite complex of free modules over polynomial ring. Is it possible in principle? (I hope so.) Here by "compute" I mean get a presentation as a cokernel of a map of free modules.

I've never used seriously any of the mathematical software yet, but I've checked manuals for Macaulay, Singular, Gap and Sage and I can't seem to find what I want. Maybe I wasn't looking very well?

Thanks.

Comment: Strange, I'd say all the software you mention would do what you're looking for, although not much more, I should say. I've recently been looking for software to deal with DGAs but I haven't been successful.

Comment: Which polynomial ring are you working over? There is no Euclidean algorithm for $\mathbb{Z}[t]$ for instance.

Comment: Check out the following chapter of the book "Computations with Macaulay2". Isn't that what you are looking for? http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/Book/ComputationsBook/chapters/completeIntersections/ci-wrapper.pdf

Comment: GAP has a homological algebra library that might answer your questions...
The description of the library is here:
http://hamilton.nuigalway.ie/Hap/www/index.html

Comment: Fernando, have you tried the DGAlgebras package for Macaulay2? Also as an aside - I'm working on "cleaning up" and adding new bits to the homological algebra packages in M2 this summer, and I'd be interested if you have any particular suggestions.

Comment: @Adam Yes, I tried, but even the suggested examples didn't work well, there were problems when defining the differential on a graded algebra by setDiff